# Javascript add parameter if "ccm_order_by_direction=desc" is in the URL

Tags: javascript, php, parameters

I am trying to find a way to add `&amp;#filterTop` to the end of the URL if `ccm_order_by_direction=desc` is in the URL.

I assume JavaScript would be the easiest, but if there is a PHP way that would work too.

The catch is that it would have to update the existing page link. The links are created in the backend and I can not edit them directly. I know I did something like this before, I can not remember how or where the info would be.

I got this far. I just don't know where to go next.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('ccm_order_by_direction=desc') !== -1) {
    let url = '<?= $actual_link ?>';
    url = url.replace('ccm_order_by_direction=desc', 'ccm_order_by_direction=desc&amp;#filterTop');
    var link = document.getElementsByClassName('.page-link');
    link.href = url;
  }
});
```

The links that needs updated look like this.

```html
<li class="page-item">
  <a class="page-link" href="/switches-damper-arm-tilt-tip-over-limit?ccm_paging_p=2&amp;ccm_order_by=popular&amp;ccm_order_by_direction=desc">2</a>
</li>
```

I would like them to look like.

```html
<li class="page-item">
  <a class="page-link" href="/switches-damper-arm-tilt-tip-over-limit?ccm_paging_p=2&amp;ccm_order_by=popular&amp;ccm_order_by_direction=desc&amp;#filterTop">2</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Anything not working with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

Without troubleshooting all your code, I can see right off the bat this line won't work:

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName('.page-link');
link.href = url;
```

For that, you'd need to iterate - in which case I recommend using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (which will return an iterable collection list) which you can then manipulate in a [forEach loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) - and change the links one by one, but you're using jQ so you can simply do:

```
$('.page-link').attr('href', newURL);
```

Which (considerately) will take care of it. However, I wanted to explore how to do this without string manipulation, so I have a solution here that uses [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) to objectify the query string and then allow you to use the baked in methods to replace the item in question. I use decodeURIComponent at the end since the URLSearchParams will decode the symbols (? #) into %d4 or whatever.

```js
let testUrl = new URL('https://this-example.com?ccm_order_by_direction=desc');

// In your case:
// let testUrl = $(location).attr('href');

$(document).ready(function() {
  let params = new URLSearchParams(testUrl.search);
  if (params.get("ccm_order_by_direction") === "desc") {
    // change the one you want
    params.set("ccm_order_by_direction", "desc&#filterTop");
    let newURL = testUrl.href + "?" + decodeURIComponent(params.toString())
    $('.page-link').attr('href', newURL);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="/switches-damper-arm-tilt-tip-over-limit?ccm_paging_p=2&amp;ccm_order_by=popular&amp;ccm_order_by_direction=desc">Inspect this link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class="page-link" href="/switches-damper-arm-tilt-tip-over-limit?ccm_paging_p=2&amp;ccm_order_by=popular&amp;ccm_order_by_direction=desc">Inspect this link too</a>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

Comment: I am very new to Stack Overflow so I struggling on figuring out how to post. But it seems I can not  put much here, so I add an Answer to my question. I will show you code copied out of my source.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let testUrl = new URL('https://www.mytinytown.com/switches-damper-arm-tilt-tip-over-limit?ccm_paging_p=2&amp;ccm_order_by=popular&amp;ccm_order_by_direction=desc');

// In your case:
// let testUrl = $(location).attr('href');

$(document).ready(function() {
  let params = new URLSearchParams(testUrl.search);
  if (params.get("ccm_order_by_direction") === "desc") {
    // change the one you want
    params.set("ccm_order_by_direction", "desc&#filterTop");
    let newURL = testUrl.href + "?" + decodeURIComponent(params.toString())
    $('.page-link').attr('href', newURL);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="page-item">
  <a class="page-link" href="https://www.mytinytown.com/switches-damper-arm-tilt-tip-over-limit?ccm_paging_p=2&amp;ccm_order_by=popular&amp;ccm_order_by_direction=desc">Change Test</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Your initial URL is not valid. You cannot use `&amp;` instead of `&` to separate your `querystring` parameters. That is why this code is not working. Change the `&amp;ccm_...` to `&ccm...` and you;ll see

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).